# ¿Cómo hacer más fácil una función para modificar los valores de una tabla?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Tengo una tabla Oferta con los siguientes valores:

```
Schema::create('ofertas', function (Blueprint $table){
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('titulo');
        $table->text('descripcion');
        $table->string('empresa');
        $table->string('sector');
        $table->date('fecha_limite');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Y tengo una función para actualizar los valores de las filas de esta tabla:

```
public function actualizar(Oferta $oferta, OfertaRequest $request){
        $oferta->titulo=$request->titulo;
        $oferta->descripcion=$request->descripcion;
        $oferta->empresa=$request->empresa;
        $oferta->sector=$request->sector;
        $oferta->fecha_limite=$request->fecha_limite;

        $oferta->save();
        return back()->with('message',['success','Oferta modificada con exito']);
    }
```

El problema es que tiene su tela ir individualmente poniendo

```
$oferta->variable=$request->variable
```

¿Hay un modo para que todos los valores del request se copien en la tabla?
Probe a poner

```
$oferta->all()=$request->all()
```

pero dio error.

Comment: Para implementar tu clase OfertaRequest tendrá que ser una clase abstracta, en tu caso no sabemos tu código de la clase OfertaRequest, puedes sustituirla con Request ´Illuminate\Http\Request´

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idealmente los atributos que deseas actualizar deberían están incluidos en la propiedad `$fillable` del modelo, posteriormente puedes usar el método fill() para actualizar el modelo, pasando como parámetro el array de los valores del request:

```
$oferta->fill($request->all());
$oferta->save();
```

Comment: Pues muchas gracias. Era esto lo que buscaba.